# Add a Service to an Application, not General

Tags: applescript

I have a script that I'd like to show up in the Services menu of the QuickTime app.

I already know how to make scripts show up in the "General" section of Services, which makes them available in every app.  And know macOS comes with categories of Services in System Preferences.

Is there a way to assign a custom script to a single application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* show up in only a given *application's* **Services** menu, then in this case set, e.g.:

**Workflow receives [Automatic (Nothing)] in [QuickTime Player]**

<sup>Note that **[Automatic (Nothing)]** is the default and can be changed as appropriate.</sup>

When setting **in [QuickTime Player]** the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* will only appear in the **Services** menu of **QuickTime Player**, although it will show under **General:** in the *application's* **Services** menu.

It this case it will also show under **General** in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

As you can see in the pictures below, **Say Foobar** shows on the **Services** menu of **QuickTime Player**, but not **Safari**.

---

**Example:**

[image]

[image]

[image]